# Multi datepicker binding

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-multidatespicker

I have got a multi datepicker class

```
$(".multiDateInput").multiDatesPicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    gotoCurrent: true
});
```

In my controller I get a list of dates

```
var temp = query.ToList().Select(r => r.Date.ToShortDateString());
```

and bind them to my model

```
model.BankHolidays = String.Join(",", temp);
```

In my view I have

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(r => r.BankHolidays, new { @class = "multiDateInput" })
```

when the view is loaded the textbox is empty. If I remove the class:

`eg @Html.TextBoxFor(r => r.BankHolidays)` it works fine

The source looks right

```
<input class="multiDateInput" id="BankHolidays" name="BankHolidays" type="text" value="01/01/2013,02/01/2013" />
```

Comment: The sentance *"but when the class is set it is not picking the values to display them"* doesn't make any sense. Can you clarify?

Comment: Nope, that doesn't clarify. Still don't know what the issue is. What does *"not picking the values to display them"* mean??

Comment: @Liam when the view is loaded the textbox is empty

Comment: why didn't you just say that! I've clarified your question and added some relevant tags (the tags you were using weren't related to your actual issue). Hopefully you'll get an answer. It looks l;ike the multidatepicker plugin (which I'm not familiar with has a bug)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to documentation you have to use 'addDates' option to set preselected dates:

```
var date = new Date();
$('#pre-select-dates').multiDatesPicker({
    addDates: [date.setDate(14), date.setDate(19)]
});
```